# How to reduce snapshot size

Tags: backup, rackspace-cloud

I'm taking a snapshot of a server running in rackspace each day and initially it was 1GB, then around 25GB when actual disk space used was that amount. I then moved data from the boot partition to block storage and the disk space used is now only 7GB but snapshots continue to be 25GB+. How can I reduce the snapshot sizes?

I have looked at the following ways to free up disk space but none of those have reduced the size.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/5980/how-do-i-free-up-disk-space

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a similar problem as with SSDs. Removing file from filesystem does not remove the data itself. Just metadata. You need to enable discard (trim) to throw away the data blocks.

I have not worked with Rackspace cloud, so I can not tell you if Rackspace storage supports this, or not. Quick googling did not tell.

Another thing worth mentioning is incremental snapshots. It [seems](http://docs.rackspace.com/cbs/api/v1.0/cbs-devguide/content/POST_createSnapshot_v1__tenant_id__snapshots_snapshots.html) it is supported. That way, your snapshot only contains what has changed since the last snapshot. That should yield initial 25G snapshot and rather small following snapshots.

Comment: tried fstrim -v to clear up the data blocks but that operation isn't supported. Contacted support and looks like it's related to the VHD format being used and the VDI chain. https://community.rackspace.com/products/f/25/t/3778